# INSERT SELECT statement with only one column for SELECT

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, select, sql-insert

I'm using SQL Server Management Studio 18 and I've got the following tables with the following columns:

**TableA**

```
[ID]
[Name]
[InternalEmplID]
```

**TableB**

```
[ID]
[InternalEmplID]
[Month]
[Year]
```

I want to do an `INSERT SELECT` into TableB, maybe something like the following:

```
INSERT INTO TableB
(InternalEmplID, Month, Year)
VALUES
((SELECT InternalEmplIDFROM TableA WHERE Name = 'John Smith'), 'July', '2020')
```

Basically, I just want to make an `INSERT SELECT` where I'm grabbing a column from another table (`InternalEmplID`), and then for the other columns (`Month` and `Year`), I want to add data that's not dependent on columns/data from another table. Is this possible? I'm not too familiar with `INSERT SELECT`'s so this is all new to me.

Comment: You can't write SQL in whatever syntax and expect SQL Server to understand and run it.  Your syntax is definitely not valid.  Please read the MSDN documentation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your query will fail *if* the `select` returns more than one row. A more flexible option is to use the `INSERT ... SELECT` syntax and provide literal values in the additional columns:

```
INSERT INTO TableB (InternalEmplID, Month, Year)
SELECT InternalEmplIDFROM, 'July', '2020' 
FROM TableA 
WHERE Name = 'John Smith'
```

Comment: Thanks--you brought up a good point. I was also thinking about if it'd be possible for me to run into any cases that would end up with more than one selected row as I was writing up that mock SQL query. Would you also be able to toss in a `TOP(1)` in that `SELECT`?

Comment: @LOL.NO.: with this syntax, the `select` part can be any valid select statement. So you can use `top`, if that's what you really want.

Answer (score 4):

You are pretty close ... simply do

```
INSERT INTO TableB (
    InternalEmplID, Month, Year
)
SELECT
    InternalEmplID, 'July', '2020'
FROM
    TableA
WHERE
    Name = 'John Smith'
```